# Accessing and populating a specific occurence of div element

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Here is the html section of the webpage

```
<div id="upload" class="panel">
        <div style="width:720px" align="left">
            <table border="0"><tr>
                <td>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                </td>
            </tr></table>
</div>
```

I populate the filetype input like

```
page.uploadFile('input[type=file]', 'test2.png');
```

This always populate the first div input attachment file type.

How can I change this to populate the first/second...till fifteenth div elements file type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `page.uploadfile` only accepts simple CSS-like selectors but without extra modifiers like `nth-child`, so there is no way to target all inputs unless they have their own classes or IDs.

But... we can manipulate the page with `page.evaluate`! Let's give them unique classes:

```
total_inputs = page.evaluate(function(){
    // Assign different class names to all file inputs
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]'), i;
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
        inputs[i].className = "file" + i;
    }
    // pass back to PhantomJS scope information about how many inputs there are
    return inputs.length;
});

// Now upload those files!
for (q = 0; q < total_inputs; ++q) {
    page.uploadFile('input[class=file' + q + ']', 'test2.png');
}
```

The result:

[image: The result]

Note that some versions of PhantomJS are incapable of uploading files.